# Extract Part of URL JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I extract just the date part from the following string?

`var string = "http://www.blah.co.uk/world/images/landing-pages/furniture/11-12-2015/furniture.jpg"`

The "furniture.jpg" part will be variable length as well as the furniture department text before the date.

Thank you,
D

Comment: string.lastIndexOf("/") or split("/") .. and move your way from there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you perhaps split by "/" and take the second to last?

```
var components = string.split("/");
var dateString = components[components.length - 2]
```

Comment: @Liam Since the array is zero-indexed, components[components.length] would be out of the array and components[components.length - 1] would be "furniture.jpg"

Comment: Ignore me, brain not firing on all cylinders... this is the answer

Comment: Whilst this works, it relies on the string being in a certain structure. That may or may not be a problem depending the context of the problem @user1389646 is trying to solve. Personally, I would prefer not to couple my code the the structure of the URL in this way.

Comment: But will it be possible at all to answer this question without making assumptions? Farnabaz solution is neat but again that assumes the url only has one date in it. Perhaps a safer assumption, perhaps not, but still an assumption.

Comment: But parsing strings is always coupled to a certain structure. Your answer @ZacBraddy is no different, it relies on data being a in a certain place in the string. If the the OP wants the second to last part of the URL then this does it and you could argue a RegEx is simply in-efficent/goldplating

Comment: These are valid points but they don't make me like this solution any more and here's is why: Yes Farnabaz's and my own Regex base solution still do assume a pattern and if this pattern changes then our solutions start failing tests cases, as you say andrss we are working with assumptions here. The difference between the solutions though is that whilst the regex based solution is expecting a certain pattern, the solution here assumes both a pattern as well as relies on the fact that the structure of the URL conforms.

Comment: This solution wants BOTH that the url contain forward slashes (which is fine, I'm just pointing out that this is a pattern you need for this to work the same as the regex does) but then it also assumes that you are looking for the working directory of the files. This makes a temporal link between the server architecture and your problem at hand. What if you chose to put a furniture.jpg inside a subfolder? The regex still works, but the substring solution does not.

Answer (score 2):

String has a great function `match`, you can pass regex (regular expression) to it and this return matches in string

```
var string = "http://www.blah.co.uk/world/images/landing-pages/furniture/11-12-2015/furniture.jpg"
string.match(/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/) // out: ["11-12-2015"]
```

if you interest in regular expression look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: I prefer this answer because it doesn't alway has to be in the same place of the url, just match the date format, nice

Comment: It's also less efficent than the substring @Thomas

Comment: For something like this efficiency is a low priority.

Comment: @Liam I prefer security over some milliseconds performance gain

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex

```
var string = "http://www.blah.co.uk/world/images/landing-pages/furniture/11-12-2015/furniture.jpg";
var iWantThisDate = /[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/.exec(string);
```

That would get you just the date pattern out of the string and put it in iWantThisDate.